# Azure AKS with multiple log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to come up with a scenario where I have multiple Kubernetes namespaces and want to set different log analytics workspaces per namespace because of the GDPR reasons.

> Use case: Integration of different log analytics workspaces to AKS and map with specific namespaces

Is there a way I can do this? As per the official documentation, only 1 log analytics workspace is supported in AKS. Anyone has any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Comment: You are right. as per MS docs only one log analytics workspace is supported in AKS. However, if you need to satisfy GDPR requirements by keeping data in different Azure geographies, you can split up the data into separate workspaces. This means that you can create separate workspaces for each namespace, and then configure each namespace to send its logs to its corresponding workspace. As per this can be achieved by creating a diagnostic setting for each namespace to send logs to its corresponding workspace. You can use Azure Policy to ensure consistent configuration across multiple namespaces.

Comment: see  [Create diagnostic settings to send platform logs and metrics to different destinations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-master-logs#configure-diagnostics-settings-to-send-logs-to-different-destinations) and -   [Prepare for multiple workspaces and tenants in Microsoft Sentinel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/prepare-multiple-workspaces#the-need-to-use-multiple-microsoft-sentinel-workspaces)

Comment: Hi @Arko I can't seem to find what you said in the first link you have given. Is it the right link? And also I would like to know, what is the difference between having one workspace per AKS cluster and having multiple diagnostic settings with different workspaces? Thank you!

Comment: Having one workspace per AKS cluster means that all the logs from that cluster will be sent to a single Log Analytics workspace. On the other hand, having multiple diagnostic settings with different workspaces means that logs from different categories will be sent to different Log Analytics workspaces.  [Create and update custom workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-enable?pivots=defender-for-container-aks&tabs=aks-deploy-portal,k8s-deploy-asc,k8s-verify-asc,k8s-remove-arc,aks-removeprofile-api#default-log-analytics-workspace-for-aks)

Comment: Thank you, I looked into this. I am still having some issues how I can only send specific namespace's logs to my other workspace with this.

Comment: @Arko I would really really love to see what you have said earlier with `As per this can be achieved by creating a diagnostic setting for each namespace to send logs to its corresponding workspace. You can use Azure Policy to ensure consistent configuration across multiple namespaces.`

Comment: Hi @Arko the last link you have shared is for azure defender. I am still wondering how this can be related to my initial requirement - having multiple log analytics workspaces for each Kubernetes namespaces.